# OS X keychain not visible to Keychain Access.app in Mavericks

Tags: command-line-interface, keychain, osx-mavericks

I've set up a keychain as follows:

```
sudo /usr/bin/security create-keychain -p 'temporaryPassword' MyKeychain.keychain
```

The keychain is present and working as shown by:

```
/usr/bin/security show-keychain-info MyKeychain.keychain
Keychain "MyKeychain.keychain" lock-on-sleep timeout=300s
```

The permissions in `~/Library/Keychains` are all consistent.

Why does Keychain `Access.app` not show MyKeychain in its **Keychains panel**?

Comment: See follow-up at https://discussions.apple.com/message/23571041#23571041

Answer (score 34):

Because MyKeychain is not in the keychain search list.

Even though the man page for `security` says that `create-keychain` adds the created keychain to the search list, it does not actually do that in 10.9.0. This seems like a bug to me, as it works as described in the man page in 10.8.5. Try this:

```
security create-keychain -p 'temporaryPassword' MyKeychain.keychain
security list-keychains
```

If you don't see MyKeychain.keychain in the resulting list, you need to add it. For example, let's say you got this list back from security list-keychains:

```
/Users/fred/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
/Library/Keychains/System.keychain
```

You can add MyKeychain to that list with this command:

```
security list-keychains -d user -s login.keychain MyKeychain.keychain
```

The instant you do that, you'll see MyKeychain show up in the "Keychains" list in Keychain Access..

Comment: Thanks! Spent whole day wondering why our build script failed after upgrading to 10.9. This is a super lifesaver, thumbs down for stupid Apple bugs/"API changes".

Comment: I believe I may be having this same problem with a slightly different setup...

My login.keychain does not appear in Keychain Access. If I add it from the File menu it appears in the list, and it appears in bold which suggests it is the default. However, if I exit Keychain Access and re-open it, it's gone.

WWG's answer suggests that there is some other file somewhere that might be causing the problem. Where is this list stored?

I also *believe* that this problem is due to permissions, because I've had a boatload of permissions problems.

Comment: Seriously life savior :)